# update QLineEdit value every n seconds

Tags: qt, refresh, qlineedit

A beginner's question but actually I'm stuck. I am not allowed to use "high-level" c++ threading function (nor pthread, nor QThread). However, there are some thread that I should create with winAPI function createThread. And those threads use to change some variables. I want to show these variables every 1 second in a QLineEdit component. So I tried a code like:

```
    stillWorking = true;
    while(stillWorking){
        ui->editElement->setText(QString::number(getVariableValue()));
        qDebug() << 'running!!!'
        Sleep(1000);
    }
```

The `stillWorking` boolean value is set to `false` when some button is clicked. That's how I hope to stop this loop. But, when I execute the code, the `editElement` isn't updated and the application stop responding. However, the `'running!!!'` string is well printed in the debug section every second. So, is there any other way to access and show my variables?

Comment: Why can't you use QThread? What do you gain by not using it, you already have a dependency on Qt anyway if you use QLineEdit.

Comment: Because it's part of the project. All threading should be done using WinAPI threading function (semaphore, mutex, ...etc...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a [`QTimer`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qtimer.html), assuming you're allowed to (even if you were allowed to use threads). Doing any sort of blocking on the UI thread will not work, it needs to be released for event processing to work, and reacting to clicks needs event processing.

The [Timers](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/timers.html) page has a bit more info and examples of how to use it. The idea here would be to create a slot that simply does:

```
ui->editElement->setText(QString::number(getVariableValue()));
```

and a repeating timer connected to that slot.

(This assumes that `getVariableValue()` is properly synchronised and does indeed see the updated value from that other thread.)

Comment: A great idea. I read the page and some other example of QTimer on google. But it seems that I cannot pass a parameter through the function in the SLOT parameter (just the type). So how do I update a specific QLineEdit? Creating a slot for every QLineEdit would be timecosting and wasting much line of code, there are too many variables to show.

Comment: Not sure I understand your setting, but seems like you could do all the updates in a single slot, or at least put the ui elements in a manageable number of groups to be updated at the same time. (You can't pass any parameter to the slot triggered by the timer.)

Comment: Well, I tried my best. I managed to use slot (many slots) without parameter by changing my code. Now it get error: `QEventDispatcherWin32::registerTimer: Failed to create a timer (???)`. Googled it but no helpful results.

Comment: Yeeaaahh!!! I should create a QTimer object rather than using the singleshot static method as in the example. It works perfectly now! thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of these two ways;

Fisrt one is explained above from Mat

Second way is if your class derivated from QObject, you can override the timerEvent

```
class MyObject : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyObject(QObject *parent = 0);

int timerID;


protected:
    void timerEvent(QTimerEvent *event);
};

MyObject::MyObject(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
{

    timerID = startTimer(1000);   // 1-second timer

}

void MyObject::timerEvent(QTimerEvent *event)
{

    ui->editElement->setText(QString::number(getVariableValue()));

    this->killTimer(timerID); // you can use here if you plan stop timer

}
```

in your function
your visible widget is updated if while loop is break else your application work but not update any gui widget while process in loop.